# How to match constructed pattern in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket, quote

I know we can pattern match using `quasiquote` patterns in Racket. For example:

```
> (match '(3) [`(,l) l])
3
```

﻿However, I'm not sure if it's possible to achieve the same result with pre-existing patterns like

```
> (define pattern '`(,l))
> pattern
'`(,l)
```

How do I inject such `pattern` into the `match` clause?

Answer (score 2):

`match` is a macro. It uses its arguments, thus the patterns, from code **before** runtime. If you check the macro stepper `` (match '(3) [`(,l) l]) `` becomes this:

```
(let ([temp1 '(3)])
  (define (fail2) 
    (match:error temp1 (syntax-srclocs (quote-syntax srcloc)) 'match))
  (cond
   [(pair? temp1)
    (let ([unsafe-car4 (unsafe-car temp1)] [unsafe-cdr5 (unsafe-cdr temp1)])
      (cond
       [(null? unsafe-cdr5)
        (syntax-parameterize
         ([fail (make-rename-transformer (quote-syntax fail2))])
         (let ([l unsafe-car4]) (let () l)))]
       [else (fail2)]))]
   [else (fail2)]))
```

If you were to use the variable `pattern` in place of `` `(,1) `` it will just think you have a pattern that matches the whole argument. As show by this expansion of `(match '(3) [pattern l])`:

```
(let ([temp1 '(3)])
  (define (fail2) 
    (match:error temp1 (syntax-srclocs (quote-syntax srcloc)) 'match))
  (syntax-parameterize ([fail (make-rename-transformer (quote-syntax fail2))])
    (let ([pattern temp1]) (let () l))))
```

Your variable `pattern` doesn't exist before long after this have happened and thus `match` cannot take dynamic patterns. You need to move your pattern logic into the macro expansion time if the reason is that you want to abstract on many patterns, but that still are computable without input.

If you need patterns to be from input you cannot use `match` in this way. Perhaps you need to make something that does something similar in runtime.

Since the example is very basic I do not know what you are trying to achieve. I'm thinking this may be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Yep, looks like XY problem to me, too.

Comment: Possibly they want to define a match expander?? If so: https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html#%28part._.Extending_match%29

Answer (score 0):

Although I’m not certain exactly what you want to accomplish, I want to point out that you can define [match expanders](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html#%28part._.Extending_match%29). Keep in mind that, like match, these exist at compile- not run-time.